# Creating a border gap

Tags: css, image, border

I'm trying to get a gap created within a div's border to fit an image, similar to this:

[image]

Is there a way to do this in pure CSS? All I can see is:

```
.box {
    background: url(img.png) bottom left;
    border-top: 1px solid #eee;
    border-left: 1px solid #eee;
}
```

But my problem is `border-right: 1px solid #eee;` creates a line on top of my image, which is of course not desired.

It needs to be responsive. This image is an example, but you get the general idea.

Comment: that's what the OP wants I think. Can be achieved by applying absolute positioning on the image

Comment: I get the idea, however, this doesn't allow for much room for responsive work. The picture shown is simple, but this also applies to a div with more content.

Comment: See my answer, this gives you the general idea. I don't know what your situation is exactly, so once you get the idea, you can work on how to position the image correctly

Comment: From what I'm seeing, there's really no way of doing this without adding an image to the HTML...

Comment: You don't want to add it to the html? You can always add a div and set the background of the div to the image and then position the div. If you are looking for a specific way to do something then give a more detailed example that mimics your issue to get better answers

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/6Ufb5/

```
div {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    position: relative;
}
img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
}
```

Give the container position relative and the img absolute, shift it to left 10px and shift it down 10px from the top and you have what you desire.
For the responsive part, that's just giving the container and/or img a % width.
Like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/6Ufb5/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using absolute positioning of the image element - and it has to be in a `<img>` element, not as the background image because it will never overlap the parent border (or even if it does by adjusting the `background-position` property, the border will lie on top of the background image... a behavior that is expected, by the way.

```
<div class="box">
    Content goes here
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" />
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.box {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #333;
}
.box img {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -1px;
    right: -1px;
}
```

---

If you want a dynamic and/or responsive solution, you might have to resort to JS to doing so - such as resizing the image depending on the box dimensions, and assigning a height to the box to take into account of the image height (since image is absolutely positioned, it is taken out of the document flow).

See fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/xH6UV/

Answer (score 0):

This might work if you can alter your markup. For accessibility I think the image should be an image and not a background, and this method is responsive (though you may want to alter margins at small sizes with media queries).

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/79Js5

```
.box {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 0 10px 10px;
    width: 40%;
}
.box img {
    margin-right: -10%;
    margin-bottom: -10%;
    width: 105%;
}

<div class="box">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100/f3f3f3" />
</div>
```

Comment: From what I'm seeing, there's really no way of doing this without adding an image to the HTML...

Comment: True, but like I said, accessibility validators will want it to be an image.

Comment: Looks like this will have to do. I will wait, however, to see if someone comes up with an alternative method.